# swap locations on the Blogger nextprev button range

Tags: blogger

I would like to swap the locations of the nextprev buttons on the Blogger page: put the Old Posts button on the left and the Recent Posts button on the right
My site [Amavero 2](https://www.amavero.fr) (in french) publish my poems. Thank's.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways you can do that.

One is simply add to the CSS, above `</head>`, the following:

```
.blog-pager {
  position: relative;
}
.blog-pager-older-link,
.blog-pager-newer-link
{
  position: absolute;
}
.blog-pager-older-link
{
  left: 0;
}
.blog-pager-newer-link
{
  right: 0;
}
```

The other way involves going into the HTML part, search for the `blog-pager` code and swap the locations of the `blog-pager-newer-link` part with the `blog-pager-older-link`.

I can't post the exact HTML codes you must search because they sometimes difer between templates except the `blog-pager` bits, UNLESS it's a personalized template.

I hope this helps.

Comment: thank you ! it works but not by placing your code above /head but by inserting it directly in the CSS lines of blog-pager. Like this: 
<code>.blog-pager {
  position : relative
  background: $(paging.background);
}

 .blog-pager-newer-link, .home-link, .blog-pager-older-link
 {
  background-color: $(content.background.color);
  padding: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  color: green!important;
}
  .blog-pager-older-link
   {
 left: 0;
}
.blog-pager-newer-link
   {
 right: 0;
}</code>

Comment: Somebody gives me something simpler : 
    `#blog-pager #blog-pager-older-link {float: left;} <br />
    #blog-pager #blog-pager-newer-link {float: right;}`